# How to add menu command to toolbar in Adobe Reader DC

Tags: adobe-reader

Is there a way to get the command "Show Cover Page in Two Page View" into the toolbar?

[image]

It is not included in the buttons that are added to the toolbar with "Show all page display tools".

I would like a one-click command to switch two page view for cover page off and on, without having to navigate through the View menu each time.

Comment: I have an Acrobat Reader machine here. That command is not part of the regular group of commands. I have looked around at several sites and I do not see a way to do this.